# How do take good close shot photos of documents

Tags: photos, focus, document-scanner

One of the purposes of my phone investment is to quickly take photos of documents.

I find this difficult.  When I hold it with my hand it takes a long time to get “focused”.
I have a Notes 3.

Stability would help of course, but don’t know exactly how to do that.  What could help is if the photo is automatically taken when focus is achieved, perhaps with “retries” until it is OK.

Comment: How is it an Android issue?

Comment: @SachinShekhar The answer might be a special-purpose camera app that can compensate for motion blur or sharpen text. For example, there's one in the "related questions" that might be useful.

Comment: I rawly remember having seen a photo app doing exactly that (auto-shoot on focus), but I do not remember which one it was...

Comment: "camera app that can compensate for motion blur " I would think you need focus before you take the shot?  Then it is a bit different for correcting for motion in a photo that is already shot.

Comment: About "Android issue".  Focusing is part of the software - so it is different from taking a good shot with a regular camera.

Comment: I found the app InstaCamera.  (Seems OK, but I don't like the way they seems to use the free version as a bait for the paid one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Evernote. It has a dedicated `Page Camera` feature for your purpose. You can continuously snap documents with it.

If you are a premium user, keywords from your snapped documents will be indexed with OCR technologies (which will be useful in searching). And, it works great (I am a premium user & I have used it). If you aren't, just buy premium subscription for 1 month... Indexing continue to exist after 1 month (but new documents won't be indexed).

Comment: I think perhaps InstaCamera is a good alterantive.  I guess a proble for both it would not work with apps thatare made to create pdf's like a scanner (Since they use the camera directly).

Comment: I have been using InstantCamera for a while now, and its definitely better than native.